How to run script ONLY when trigger on wired and wifi?
I read a lot of examples on the internet. I put the script
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d

but the script does not work, that I want.
I want a script to start in my debian OS o n l y  when wired connection and wifi connection trigger up and connect. I don't want to start the script when NetworkManager.service starts.
All other script on the internet run when NetworkManager.service starts.
How to do it?

Feel free to adapt my net-o-matic script. https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.
